# Accessing information from Omniauth facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, eclipse-juno

I need to create a table with user information from `omniauth Facebook` in Ruby on Rails.

I have to set up a table for all the users that use my system. I use Facebook for login-authentication and I would like to fetch Firstname, Lastname, Photo, and Email from Facebook and store them in a local database which I will be linking to many other databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the information from

```
data = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
```

Put this line in your action in the controller and the variable `data` will have all the information you require in the form of `Hash` which you can easily obtain.

By inspecting the data in yaml format, it will look something like this

```
--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
provider: facebook
uid: '100000003334572'
info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash
  nickname: amit.thawait
  email: amit17thawait@gmail.com
  name: Amit Thawait
  first_name: Amit
  last_name: Thawait
  image: http://graph.facebook.com/100000003334572/picture?type=square
  description: I do, what I feel is right.
  urls: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    Facebook: http://www.facebook.com/amit.thawait
  location: Mumbai, Maharashtra, India
  verified: true
credentials: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  token:   BAABxTjZCB4e8BAAgSGOoZAmpcDaWjaPM3muL0ZCyEJuLMZAkj5RBnlKy8USptBk4FDSlVyjSszAz1spo5J3K5lUrd6jkU87ZAvv37FJqzATLpV048UxjvhZBDaMZAVJKn9hUFfpJfuikRs4rHIkfvf6kPqNJw2BK8QOIObiBvopQfy0hGbJWBegjomnc9DY4IwZD
  expires_at: 1371899187
  expires: true
extra: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  raw_info: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
    id: '100000003334572'
    name: Amit Thawait
    first_name: Amit
    last_name: Thawait
    link: http://www.facebook.com/amit.thawait
    username: amit.thawait
    hometown: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      id: '108844689143285'
      name: Korba, Chhattisgarh, India
    location: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      id: '114759761873412'
      name: Mumbai, Maharashtra, India
    bio: I do, what I feel is right.
    work:
    - !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      employer: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '108134792547341'
        name: Tata Consultancy Services
      location: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '114759761873412'
        name: Mumbai, Maharashtra, India
      position: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '149467135066791'
        name: Systems Engineer
      start_date: 2010-01
    education:
    - !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      school: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '115059778505995'
        name: KENDRIYA VIDYALAYA KSTPS KORBA
      year: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '194878617211512'
        name: '2002'
      type: High School
    - !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      school: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '110549502306553'
        name: Vikas Airport Campus, Vishakhapatnam (A.P)
      year: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '113125125403208'
        name: '2004'
      type: High School
    - !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      school: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '209094152551215'
        name: Bhilai Institute of Technology, Durg (C.G.)
      year: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '136328419721520'
        name: '2009'
      type: College
    - !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
      school: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '129487623787373'
        name: Vikas Airport Campus,Vishakhapatnam
      type: College
      with:
      - !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
        id: '100000414638041'
        name: Surjit Basu
    gender: male
    email: amit17thawait@gmail.com
    timezone: 5.5
    locale: en_US
    verified: true
    updated_time: '2013-04-18T17:22:04+0000'
```

You can also have a look at Facebook's Graph API

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/graphapi/